# Calculate elapsed time from two separate inputs using function and header file

Tags: c++, elapsedtime

I am writing a code that takes two user inputted times and switches them all to seconds(using the function) gives me the elapsed time and stores it in my header file, then writes to screen elapsed time is hh:mm:ss. I am having trouble in my function with Time1. and Time.2 and the delim1 and delim2 that is supposed to enter a colon in. i am coming up with errors and cannot get it to run. I am sure there are other problems. I really need help I am stuck! All is appreciated.
say I enter 12:15:30 for start time and end time 13:30:30 it should output my elapsed time is 1:15:00. 
Can anyone figure it out? It sounds basic but I am lost. I cant even get  the numbers to read in. here is my code: *Updated* should compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "C1A7E1_MyTime.h"

using namespace std;

void DeterminedElapsedTime(const MyTime& Time1,
const MyTime& Time2,
double& ElapsedTimeAsSeconds);

int main()
{
 char *delim1 = ":";


MyTime Time1;
MyTime Time2;

cout << "Input first clocktime and second clocktime (hh:mm:ss  hh:mm:ss)     \n";

cin >> Time1.hours >> delim1 >> Time1.minutes >> delim1 >> Time1.seconds;
cin >> Time2.hours >> delim1 >> Time2.minutes >> delim1 >> Time2.seconds;

// do validation of input, minutes and seconds 0 to 59

double ElapsedTimeAsSeconds = 0.0;

DeterminedElapsedTime(Time1, Time2, ElapsedTimeAsSeconds);
// need to do something with the answer - Convert to HH:MM:SS ?

return 0;
}
//function:
#include"C1A7E1_MyTime.h"
void DeterminedElapsedTime(const MyTime& Time1, const MyTime& Time2, double&      ElapsedTimeAsSeconds)
{

double elapsedtime;

double Time1AsSeconds = Time1.hours * 3600 + Time1.minutes * 60 +   Time1.seconds;
double Time2AsSeconds = Time2.hours * 3600 + Time2.minutes * 60 + Time2.seconds;

ElapsedTimeAsSeconds = Time1AsSeconds - Time2AsSeconds;
}
//header file
struct MyTime {unsigned int hours,  minutes, seconds; };
```

Comment: The code you showed does not compile. Please cut and paste the shown code, try to compile it, figure out why it doesn't compile, fix it, then edit your question, and replace the shown code with one that correctly compiles. All questions on stackoverflow.com of this type must include a [mcve].

Comment: "Coming up with errors" is not enough, *what* errors? Build errors? Runtime errors or crashes? Unexpected results? Please elaborate, and most importantly *show* us the "errors".

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use the [c-style date and times functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime) or the [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)  ?

Comment: Your use of `cin` here isn't very user friendly (and might be the cause of your input problems). Consider reading in a single line of text for each time, and then parsing it.

Comment: I get it to compile but am still getting caught up during the compile..